# Sort with the header after research

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I have a function like this:

```
def research(self):

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE name_simple LIKE ?")

    query.bindValue(0, "%" + liste.simpleChar(self.research_bar.text()) + "%")
    query.exec_()

    self.modele.setQuery(query)

    self.tableau.doubleClicked.connect(self.launchFile)
    self.tableau.setModel(self.modele)
```

wich performs a request in a database, and returns some videos. My horizontal header has the following fields : "name", "votes", "date". But when I click on one of these fields, the view turns back to the orginal model, with all the videos, not only the ones returned by the function.

I define my header like that:

```
self.horizontal_header = QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal) 
self.horizontal_header.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
self.horizontal_header.setClickable(True)
self.tableau.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(5, QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)
self.tableau.resizeColumnToContents(1)
self.tableau.setHorizontalHeader(self.horizontal_header)
self.tableau.hideColumn(0)
self.tableau.hideColumn(2)
self.tableau.hideColumn(4)
#self.tableau.hideColumn(6)
self.tableau.hideColumn(7)
self.tableau.horizontalHeader().moveSection(5, 0)
self.tableau.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(72)
self.tableau.setColumnWidth(5, 127)
self.tableau.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.tableau.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

And I can't sort the returned videos by name, vote or date. Do you have an idea about why I have this behavior ?

Comment: Please clean it up so it is properly formatted and remove French comments.

Comment: Could you post a minimal version of your code that reproduces the issue? The details you provided aren't enough to understand what is going wrong

Comment: Here is a screenshot: [screen](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/6216/screenshot7f9c7a32.png). As you can see, after a research on a key word, the files are not sorted by date. If I click again on date, I go back to the complete view, displaying all the videos, like without any research.

Comment: Anyway, I think  [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) would be much more indicated for this kind of task

Comment: Crap. So I made a column with a simplified name in my sqlite database for nothing ? I can't use a 'like' research ?